# How to upload a CSV file from Cloud Functions to Cloud Storage in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a CSV file that was created from an object in a Cloud Function to a Cloud Storage bucket. I am currently using the @google-cloud/storage library to handle the uploads. The CSV file is saved in the tmp folder of the Cloud Function instance.

### here is my current implementation

---

```js
const saveCsv = async () => {
  const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;

  const data = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      surname: 'Doe',
      age: 35,
      gender: 'M',
      city: 'New York',
    },
    {
      name: 'Jane',
      surname: 'Doe',
      age: 28,
      gender: 'F',
      city: 'Los Angeles',
    },
  ];

  const csvPath = '/tmp/output.csv';
  const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
    path: csvPath,
    header: [
      { id: 'orderNumber', title: 'orderNumber' },
      { id: 'zipcode', title: 'zipcode' },
      { id: 'address', title: 'address' },
      { id: 'phoneNumber', title: 'phoneNumber' },
      { id: 'name', title: 'name' },
    ],
  });
  csvWriter.writeRecords(data);

  const storage = new Storage();
  const bucketName = 'order_numbers';

  storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(csvPath);
};


exports.uploadToDrive = functions
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    await save(todayIntentData);
});
```

### Result

`Function execution took 60001 ms, finished with status: 'error'`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We need to see your entire code in order to help you (what is the `save()` method, when and how do you call the `saveCsv()` one?)